# What to best use to build an artificial wall in my house?

Tags: walls, advice

trying to build a wall in my new rented house to separate one big room into two smaller ones. Any recommendations on what to use and on how to build this?

Comment: This can't be answered without you first describing how the building structure is done. Adding several dozen or maybe hundred or maybe even thousand (depending on material) pound wall requires detailed analysis. It's one thing if you have a concrete plate as the floor base and another thing if you have floor based on wooden beams.

Comment: A temporary wall or a permanent one?

Comment: Search for a folding wall/room divider...only thing you'd need to install is the ceiling track.

Answer (score 2):

Given that it's a rental, I'm assuming this is intended to be a temporary structure. I'd look at using some sort of storage as a wall. The [Ikea Expedit](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/40047675/) shelves work well as room dividers, if you're only looking to divide the space.

Comment: Great,thx a mill for y advise!